# Angular service worker deploy breaking changes

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

During the current work on my app, there are some breaking changes in the API (backend) the app uses.

Because the app is using Angular's service worker, it means that the first time the returning users will go to the app several things might not work correctly until the service worker will update the relevant files.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before? 
What possible solutions are there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- If you have breaking changes on front-end. SW caches the whole app, so if the app is in version 1, you deploy version 2 (without removing javascript files and resources from version 1), when the user comes back it will load all javascript files from version 1 and it will start downloading version 2.
- If you have breaking changes on back-end. You will have to keep legacy endpoints or develop a front-end system to force users to update. Force updates would't always happen.

Comment: This is indeed breaking changes on the back-end. Are there any best practices for that? also keep having more and more legacy endpoints doesn't seem like the correct way to handle it

Comment: @MatanKadosh Yes. You have to version your API. For example, you can send an http header `APIversion: 1.0`. When you release a new versions, you will have to support N older versions, for example 2. If your api is in version 3, you mark as deprecated endpoints of version 2 and 1. And when you release version 4, in this release you delete endpoints of version 1 cause you support the last 2. This is then way to manage API versions.